# How to specify dependencies' version in `pip install` command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I specify installing `pytest` in Drone pipeline as below:

```
pip install -q pytest
```

it used to work well until a few days ago when it suddenly showed below error:

```
+ python -m pytest test/test_dai_adrecogzer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytest.py", line 14, in <module>
    from _pytest.fixtures import fillfixtures as _fillfuncargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 16, in <module>
    from more_itertools import flatten
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from more_itertools.more import *  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 329
    def _collate(*iterables, key=lambda a: a, reverse=False):
                               ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Searching around I found a [recently post SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648246/invalid-syntax-in-more-itertools-when-running-pytest#) that seems to closely link to what I am looking for. The reason seems to be because of recently released version 6.0 of `more-itertools`. The accepted answer suggests to `spin` to some specific version of `more-itertools`:

```
setuptools.setup(
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['mock', 'more-itertools<6.0.0', 'pytest'],
    test_suite='tests',
    python_requires='>=2.7',
)
```

How could I apply this suggestion to my issue? More specifically, how could I specify version `<6.0.0` of `more-itertools` when install `pytest` using `pip install -q pytest` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could specify a version of pytest that has an old version of more-itertools (for ex: pip install pytest==3.5.0)

I will not advise to install pytest with another version of more-iterators, other then one specified in setuptools because it may cause other crushes(pytest it may depend at some point on some features that your downgraded version doesn't have).

Comment: Oh yes, I go with `pip install -q pytest==3.4.2` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [pytest package specs on PyPI](https://pypi.org/pypi/pytest/json), the package requires `more-itertools >=4.0.0`. I would assume that, if you explicitly install any suitable version of `more-itertools` below 6.0.0 and above or equal 4.0.0, prior to running `pip install -q pytest`, the dependency check for `more-itertools` would already be satisfied and you could install the most recent version of `pytest`.